Groovy Builder- Unable to construct payload while inserting JSONArray
I was struggling to construct a JSON payload using Groovy Builder .
Expected JSON payload
{
  "subscriptions": [
    {
      "subscriptionsId": "1243232",
      "subscriptionName": "Employee",
      "subscribedCountries": [
        {
          "id": "901f5e1d-1139-49f1-a91e-6324232151bf",
          "name": "${countryName}",
          "countryId": "${countryId}"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

In one JSON variable json2 , I am constructing the JSON array subscribedCountries using the retrieved values ${countryName} ,${countryId}.
Then inserting above Json array in my actual json payload json1 .
Problem - I am unable to insert the json array to my actual json payload
Please see below code
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder;
def builder = new JsonBuilder();

def json2=builder {}
json2.put('subscribedCountries',[]);
for(int i=2;i<=20;i++){
    json2.subscribedCountries.add([
    currencyId:vars.get('currencyId_'+i),
    countryId:vars.get('countryId_'+i),
    status:'Active'
    ])
}

def json1=builder {}
json1.put('subscriptions',[]);
json1.subscriptions.add([
'subscriptionsId':'1243232',
'subscriptionName':'Employee',
***json2***         // Getting error here . Not sure how to implement 
])


You need to convert json2 to Map or ArrayList first, something like:
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(json2.toString())

and then you will be able to use this json in the JsonBuilder class.
More information:

Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON
Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?

